# Hiding content issue in mails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, yahoo

I'm making an html mail but I have some problem with the hiding content in yahoo and outlook mail. I use this class for showing/hiding content according to the device:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {


 .hide-on-med-and-down {
    display: none !important;
    visibility:hidden !important;
    max-height:0px !important;
    max-width:0px !important;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    mso-hide:all !important;

  }
}
```

In yahoo mail the content isn't shown but there's a blank empty window in which the content should appear. With outlook the content isn't hidden instead - no problems on gmail.

Thanks!

Comment: Mail doesnt take classes. you have to give them inline

Comment: All other classes work, only this don't work :/

Comment: [This link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) will help you.

Comment: You can not use classes on mails.

Comment: I use velocity with a template, the css is all in style tag